# What is the correct way to change the managed cursor of a ListActivity

Tags: android, cursor, listactivity

I have a ListActivity at the top of which I want a spinner to allow th user select what the ListView should actually display.

In the onCreate method I instanciate my first cursor and call startManagingCursor(). I also instanciate a custom CursorAdapter in charge of rendering the view.

What I want to know is the correct way to change the cursor when the user selects an item in the filter spinner.

What I'm doing is add a OnItemSelectedListener to the spinner and inside the onItemSelected() method I create a new Cursor then new CursorAdapter and then call

stopManagingCursor(currentCursor);
currentCursor = newCursor;
startManagingCursor(currentCursor);
setListAdapter(newAdapter);

Is this an appropriate way to do this ? 
How else should/could I do it ? 
Am I forgetting something ? 
Is this ugly ?

Here's some code :

```
public class MyListActivity extends ListActivity {


private Spinner typeFilterSpinner;

private MyListAdapter cursorAdapter;

private Cursor currentCursor;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);

    typeFilterSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.TypeFilterSpinner);

    typeFilterSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new SpinnerItemSelectedListener());

    currentCursor = MyDAO.getInstance().getMyCursor(null);
    startManagingCursor(currentCursor);

    cursorAdapter = new SelectionListAdapter(this, currentCursor);
    setListAdapter(cursorAdapter);
}

class SelectionListAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

     public FavouriteLocationSelectionListAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor){
        super(context, cursor, true);

        [....] other initialization stuff here
    }
    [....] overriden rendering methods here
}   

public class SpinnerItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,View view, int pos, long id) {

        Long mi = spinnerItems.get(pos);
        Cursor newCursor = MyDAO.getInstance().getMyCursor(mi);

        //TODO maybe call setCursor on the adapter here instead of instanciating a new cursor

        SelectionListAdapter newAdapter = 
            new SelectionListAdapter(MyListActivity.this, newCursor);

        stopManagingCursor(currentCursor);
        currentCursor = newCursor;
        startManagingCursor(currentCursor);
        setListAdapter(newAdapter);

    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {
      // woooork ?
    }
}
```

}

Thats the idea.

Thanks for helping !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stopManagingCursor` doesn't close the `Cursor`, so you'll want to do that when you are switching them. As you point out in your code, it be better to keep the same adapter, and give it the new cursor. And as a bonus, calling `CursorAdapter.changeCursor(Cursor)` will close the old `Cursor` for you.

Comment: Thanks Jason. Also concerning threads, should I create my new cursor in a separate thread ?

Comment: It really depends on what type of cursor you are using and how fast it is. In practice, I don't think most devs do this unless they are dealing with a lot of data or the performance issues are noticeable. There is also the new [`CursorLoader`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html) API in Honeycomb.